# Удаление значения, если есть вхождение в list

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, list, список

Есть список:

```
listt = ['testzxc','someqwe','thisert']
key = 'test'
```

Надо удалить значение в list, если есть вхождение по key.
**Можно сделать, например, через filter или lambda?**

Вот мое решение, обычное:

```
listt = ['testzxc', 'someqwe', 'thisert']
new_listt = []
key = 'test'
for item in listt:
    if key in item:
        next
    new_listt.append(item)
print(new_listt)
```

PS Хочу сделать это через `while` или `for`, но есть ли магия *python*, какое-то изящное решение?

Comment: ваш код не работает. замените next на continue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно и с `filter`, и с `lambda`:

```
key = 'test'
my_list = ['testzxc', 'someqwe', 'thisert']

new_list = list(filter(lambda i: key not in i , my_list))
```

```
>>> new_list
['someqwe', 'thisert']
```

но старый добрый list comprehension все же понятнее, как по-мне:

```
new_list = [i for i in my_list if key not in i]
```

Comment: используй `not in`

Comment: @TigerTV.ru спасибо, у автора там ```if key in item```, поэтому, наверное

Answer (score 3):

Через filter:

```py
listt = ['testzxc','someqwe','thisert']
key = 'test'
*listt, = filter(lambda x: x.find(key) == -1, listt)
print(listt)
```